# Can't display image from media subdirectory

Tags: django

If I load image like this:

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}sub/test.jpg" />
```

it does not work, but if the image is not in a subdirectory it work fine...

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}test.jpg" />
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/myApp/media'
```

urls.py

```
(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
 'django.views.static.serve',
 {
     'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
     'show_indexes': True
 }),
```

I checked file/folder permissions and everything is fine.

Django version is 1.7.1

Comment: Does the `MEDIA_ROOT` need to end in a slash?

Comment: To narrow the issue down, does it work using the documented way to serve media files in development? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: @jproffitt I've added slash at the end but there is no change

Comment: @KevinCherepski I've tried with `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` but the image still does not show

Comment: What error are you getting in the browser logs? Or, what is the final URL generated in the HTML code?

Comment: @dillobird `<img src="/media/sub/test.jpg" class="fxkmlpttwztnedzjceux">` this is what I get from Firebug. I don't know why this class appears, but it seems it did not have any CSS rules. There are no 404 or other errors. If I try to reach `http://localhost:8000/media/sub/test.jpg` in new tab there is no problem, but if I set this url to src of the img tag it did not shows.

Comment: It turns out that I have to add one more `/` between `MEDIA_URL` and image path - `<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/sub/test.jpg" />`. In the browser path looks like this: `/media//sub/test.jpg`

Comment: Yes this work now with double slashes.